# Scrapy crawling multiple sites from the same domain

Tags: python, web-crawler, cross-domain, scrapy

I'm crawling a site with Scrapy and using 2 differente pages for resource crawling, but they are at the same domain.

Should I create 1 spider for each one of those different pages or just use conditionals to control the flux of my spider and save different XPath contents?

Comment: It depends on the desired scalability and how similar the pages are.

Comment: Each page have its own characteristics and different data to be crawled.